# curl is giving wrong result via ssh

Tags: ssh, unix, curl, unix-shell, command-line-interface

Curl is working fine on the node itself:

```
[ec2-user@smokebase1 ~]$ curl -s -I --retry 3 --header 'Host: smoke-base.dev-test.com' localhost:8080/test/api/search?where=where%20%2Fxml%2Fitem%2Fcategory%20is%20not%20%27dog%25%27 | grep "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" | wc -l
1
[ec2-user@smokebase1 ~]$ exit
logout
Connection to 10.4.11.14 closed.
```

but not giving right result with ssh command although

```
[vsha@ip-10-4-11-25 ~]$  ssh ec2-user@10.4.11.14 'curl -s -I --retry 3 --header 'Host: smoke-base.dev-test.com' localhost:8080/test/search?where=where%20%2Fxml%2Fitem%2Fcategory%20is%20not%20%27dog%25%27 | grep "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" | wc -l'
0
```

Comment: Did you try putting that inside a bash script and executing that instead? Also what do you mean by "wrong result" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem will almost certainly be to do with quoting. By trying to put `'` around your whole ssh command line, they will match up with those already in your curl command and produce unexpected results.

You could try changing the `'` for `"` in your curl command then wrap the whole ssh command in `'`

Comment: @lain Thanks for your quick reply. It got resolve :)